# Преобразование чисел между системами счисления

Tags: c++, конвертация, системы-счисления

Есть ли в языке C++ встроенный конвертер чисел из одной системы счисления в другую? Может есть какая-то библиотека, которая облегчает данную задачу?

Comment: Встречали, в том числе и здесь - много-много-много раз, поиск к вашим услугам. Не говоря уж о стандартных библиотечных функциях типа `strtol()`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для представления чисел в восьмеричной, десятичной и шестнадцатиричной сс в стандартной библиотеке есть манипуляторы [std::oct](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/oct/), [std::dec](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/dec/) и [std::hex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/), соответственно:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int i;
    std::cout << "hex: ";
    std::cin >> std::hex >> i;

    std::cout << "oct: ";
    std::cout << std::oct << i;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

В `cstdlib` есть функция [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/):
**char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );**
Где base - численное основание, используемое для представления значения в виде строки, от 2 до 36, где, например, 10 означает десятичную базу, 16 шестнадцатеричную и 2 бинарную.

Пример использования:

```
int main ()
{
  int i;
  char buffer [33];
  printf ("Enter a number: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);
  itoa (i,buffer,10);
  printf ("decimal: %s\n",buffer);
  itoa (i,buffer,16);
  printf ("hexadecimal: %s\n",buffer);
  itoa (i,buffer,2);
  printf ("binary: %s\n",buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Стоит добавить, что [*This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers.*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/)